# Basic introductory quantum mechanics question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability

> Given that $\psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{32 \pi a_{0}^{3}}}(2-\frac{r}{a_0})exp(\frac{-r}{2a_0})$ is a wavefunction of the hydrogen atom, write down the probability density for r and calculate the ratio for $a_0$ and $3a_0$.

I'm just wondering if someone could point out where i went wrong, the book says that the answer is $\frac{e^2}{9}$ but I get $\frac{e^2}{3}$, here's what I did:

The probability density for $r$ is $\langle r\rangle = \psi^{*}r\psi$ and since $\psi$ is real this becomes
$$\langle r\rangle = \frac{1}{32\pi a_{0}^{3}}r(2-\frac{r}{a_0})^2exp(\frac{-r}{a_0})$$
Therefore:

$$\langle a_0\rangle = \frac{1}{32\pi a_{0}^{2}}e^{-1}$$

$$\langle3a_0\rangle = \frac{3}{32\pi a_{0}^{2}}e^{-3}$$

So the ratio is 
$$\frac{\langle a_0\rangle}{\langle3a_0\rangle} = \frac{e^2}{3}$$

Can anyone see where I went wrong, or is the answer in the book wrong? I feel like my answer makes more sense, the particle is more likely to be found at $\langle a_0\rangle$ than it is at $\langle 3a_0\rangle$ so the ratio should be greater than one.

Comment: The probability of finding the electron between $r$ and $dr$ is $\psi^{*} \psi \space 4\pi r^2 dr$ i.e. multiply by the volume of the spherical shell lying between $r$ and $dr$.

Comment: The probability density is $|\psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\text d\mathbf r=|\psi(\mathbf{r})|^24\pi r^2\,\text dr$, not  $r|\psi(\mathbf{r})|^2$.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: isn't the probability density $|\psi(\mathbf{r})|^2$ and the probability $|\psi(\mathbf{r})|^2 dV$? $|\psi(\mathbf{r})|^2d\mathbf{r}$ is neither.

Comment: As Physics SE is a non research-level site, such basic technical questions should be allowed. In addition, the OP shows effort so the close votes are not justified IMHO.

Comment: @Dilaton: there seems to be an emerging consensus that we close homework like questions to keep them off the home page but give appropriate hints as comments. This seems to me to work well. Perhaps user78655 would like to comment?

Comment: @JohnRennie to me there seems to be no consensus on this, when looking for example at the regularly happening considerable disagreement in the review queues with always the same (5-7) people voting to close and others (3-4 people) voting to leave open. I still strongly disagree with [tagging](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5372/2751) any question involving LaTex or some calculations as homework, or even closing them as off topic for that reason, in particular [high-level ones](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5369/2751).

Comment: @JohnRennie the same disagreement can be seen in the reopen queue, when the (3-5) reviewers who are rather in favor of techical questions try to reopen somtheing, which always gets prevented by the other group of 5-7 reviewers. So I really think that speaking of a consensus is premature ... The increasing tagging and closing of technical (even very high-level) questions as homework is what prevents me from asking new questions on this site too BTW :-/